# TypeError: x.include is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm new on JS. In this code `country` is variable. Results can contain multiple answers at the same time 53,110,122 etc. And for example if I results have 68 I should get it but I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: country.include is not a function`

```
var country         = 68;
if (country.includes(68)) {
var country         = 3;
}
if (country.includes(53)) {
var country         = 138;
}
```

In Python we can do this with `if "x" in country` . Any ideas for JS?

Note: If results have 68 and 53 same time, code working.

Comment: Method is [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), *not* `.include()`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Sorry this is typo. I fixed it

Comment: What is `response.country`? This still looks difficult to reproduce and most likely due to a typo somewhere. e.g. if `response.country` is `1, 2, 68` then this code works as intended.

Comment: Actually no this code is making a request elsewhere and getting a response. Just country is not constant and I put it to show it.

Comment: Please can you give an example of what value in `response.country` causes the TypeError. If necessary add `console.log(response.country)` to find out what value is causing the error.

Comment: result `68` for country showing error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`includes` is a function built-in for arrays. You can use this function with Arrays only or with "values of an Object" which are also an array. Before applying this function to your array which is "country", You have to confirm that whether it is array or not. for that we have a built-in function with `Arrays` as `Array.isArray(country)`. This function returns `true` if the provided parameter is an array and vice versa.
`if(Array.isArray(country)) {... your checking conditions here}`
[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp#:%7E:text=The%20includes()%20method%20returns,()%20method%20is%20case%20sensitive.) is simple exercise for `include` from w3school.
Might be helpful. Thanks

Comment: I see `Array.isArray` and this is returns true and false. How can I use this for this case? I need to use If.

Comment: before checking whether country includes a value or not you can check if(Array.isArray(country)) {... your checking conditions here}

Comment: Oh okay! Please add `if(Array.isArray(country)) {... your checking conditions here}` in your answer.

Comment: Added as you suggested